# Importação única - AJAX / Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Olá,

Na minha página, ao carregar um JSON ele deve ser integrado ao arquivo. Isso funciona. O que eu queria é que ele fizesse essa importação apenas uma vez, se não ele carrega o mesmo array quantas vezes eu solicitar.
Tentei fazer criar uma variável booleana pra que quando eu clicasse a primeira vez carregasse o JSON, mas depois não mais. Podem me ajudar?

```
var botaoAdicionar = document.querySelector("#btn-buscar");

botaoAdicionar.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", "https://api-pacientes.herokuapp.com/pacientes");

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var erroAjax = document.querySelector("#erro-ajax");
    if( xhr.status == 200) {
      erroAjax.classList.add("invisivel");
      var resposta = xhr.responseText;
      var pacientes = JSON.parse(resposta);

      pacientes.forEach(function(paciente) {
        adicionaPacienteNaTabela(paciente);
      });

    }else {
      erroAjax.classList.remove("invisivel");
    }

  });

  xhr.send();

});
```

Comment: Oi Patrick não vejo nenhum ajax no teu código... terás esquecido algo?

Comment: Oi Sergio... eu havia copiado o arquivo errado. Corrigi.

Comment: Ok, então e em cada click o que deve acontecer? esse `.forEach` deve correr na mesma se o ajax não for preciso porque `pacientes` já existe? ou todo esse código deve correr só uma vez?

Comment: O que acontece: a cada vez que clico no botão, o array que está na api é carregado no minha página (uma lista de clientes). 

O que deveria acontecer: clicar uma vez, carregar esse array e caso eu clicasse novamente, não deveria (porque já foi carregado anteiormente)

Answer (score 1):

O que se faz para casos destes é remover o auscultador do evento e desabilitar o botão depois de carregar uma vez... isso poderia ser assim:

```js
const botaoAdicionar = document.querySelector("#btn-buscar");
const carregarPacientes = function() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  const.open("GET", "https://api-pacientes.herokuapp.com/pacientes");

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const erroAjax = document.querySelector("#erro-ajax");
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      erroAjax.classList.add("invisivel");
      const pacientes = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      pacientes.forEach(adicionaPacienteNaTabela);
      botaoAdicionar.removeEventListener("click", carregarPacientes);
      botaoAdicionar.disabled = true;
    } else {
      erroAjax.classList.remove("invisivel");
    }
  });
  xhr.send();
};

botaoAdicionar.addEventListener("click", carregarPacientes);
```

Comment: Irei apagar a minha resposta, incluímos quase ao mesmo tempo e está igual! Quer dizer a sua ta melhor que ficou em uma só :)

Comment: @LeAndrade é... saíram do forno ao mesmo tempo :)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal!!